# Legion 5i with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS screen brightness control

Tags: ubuntu, lenovo-laptop, power-management

I know this question has been asked many times since last year, but I can't seem to find the definitive "Oh, it's been solved" answer.

I've had the issue since I bought the Legion 5i. Initially tried 6 months ago with installing Linux Mint. Had so many issues I decided to go with Windows. I'm now on Ubuntu. It's great, but the only problem is the screen brightness.

HOWEVER... I see that the screen is dimmed when it is about to go blank (from settings, screen is blank after 1 minute). Where can I find that setting and possibly tell it that I not only want you to dim the screen to 0 after 1 minute, but if I issue the command--dim it to my specified brightness level as well?

I've tried everything it seems (editing files, adding lines to files like in grub and all that jazz), I mean I can't recall every single detail, it was months ago and I literally tried to get this working for a month. Now I'm back, different (kinda) operating system, and I'm seeing the screen dim so there has to be a way.

One last note, I'm using NVIDIA 460.39 Driver with graphics set to hybrid (I need it like this).

That is the entire point of this, is that I want my GPU for computing and idle when not in use. I want my screen brightness to adjust to increase the battery life. I know in Windows 10 I could squeeze 8 hours out of it when only playing music and brightness all the way down.

Let me know if you need anymore information and thank you for your help.